# Log info for unhandled exception during Azure initialization?

Tags: c#, azure, error-handling, azure-storage

I have deployed a site into Azure using VS 2010's **Publish** function. After VS says the deployment succeeds, I go to the old Azure dashboard and For the status it cycles through a few different status' (Initializing, Recovering, Recycling, etc) but all of them have **Unhandled Exception** at the end. I've seen a [few](http://blogs.staykov.net/2009/12/windows-azure-role-stuck-in.html) [other](http://blogs.staykov.net/2009/12/another-common-reason-for-windows-azure.html) posts about this type of error but unfortunately they havent resolved the issue for me so now I just want to see the exception.

How do I see what the exception was?

Comment: Almost every time this has happened to me it has been because of an assembly that is not on the Azure instance but is GACed on my local machine. Check you copy local flags for items that would not be on the stock instance of 2008 or 2008r2 server depending on what you chose for os family

Comment: Thanks. I did a quick scan earlier and I thought the assemblies were all `Copy Local` but maybe I should check again.

Comment: @DennisBurton Do you know if `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime` needs to be copied over? I also have several `System.*` assemblies not set to copy over.

Comment: ServiceRuntime does not need to be copied over. StorageClient and Diagnostics should be. Rob Gillen wrote a tool a while back to view assemblies on the server at http://gacviewer.cloudapp.net/ . Based on the version number it is a bit out of date though. You could create an empty mvc project with RD set up on deployment and have a look at what is on the instance. Just make sure the osfamily and osversion are the same as what you are deploying you app to

Comment: @DennisBurton Great resource! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should activate Remote Desktop. Even though it's cycling, if you try to connect a few times you'll be able to connect.

Once you are connected, simply do the following:

1. Start
2. Run
3. eventvwr.exe
4. Choose the **Application** log

Then you'll see the error (might even be a warning), and you'll be able to see what's going on. Most of the time this is simply caused by a missing assembly.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a shot later (deployments take over an hour and I'm already in the middle of one and I havent enabled RD yet).

Comment: I got in. Thanks. Unfortunately, there is nothing there, but that is a different question.